# Set unsaved file marker on close button

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos

How do I control the unsaved file marker in OS X? I'm talking about this little dot on the close button of an application. I don't know how it is actually called, so I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I finally [found it](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It's in the NSWindow class.

Comment: You should improve your own answer. Your current answer won't help other people. Did you mean [`setDocumentEdited`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-BABBACAB)?